# Run .bash_profile when I open a new terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

When I open a new terminal, I have to run :
`source ~/.bash_profile` every time...

How can I automate this ?
I have read lot of thing on internet but I don't find any clear response.
Thanks

FYI : when I run
`echo $SHELL`
I get `/bin/zsh`

Comment: Why do you run zsh if you want your .bash_profile to be executed? This sounds to me like ordering milk if you want to drink beer..... zsh is sourcing a bunch of files when it starts up, but which ones they are, depends on whether it is a login shell and whether it is inactive. See the section titled _INVOCATION_ in `man zsh`, where the files involved are described in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your shell is **zsh**, it loads *.zshrc* file when terminal (in login mode) started.

Either you have to change your shell to be /bin/bash or copy .bash_profile into .zshrc

to change the shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

to copy profile:

```
cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.zshrc
# or create a symlink
ln -s ~/.bash_profile ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: thanks @kofemann  for your answer. 

I tried the first option but it doesn't work  `chsh: no changes made`

I didn't have any .zshrc fil so I create it and copy my bash_profile to zsh

Comment: Just to note, on macOS `.zprofile` is also being sourced, since terminal editors typically start a login shell. Under no circumtstances should you simply create link to `bash` configuration files for use by `zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

As zsh terminal load .zshrc when started.
So we can loading .bash_profile actively by

```
echo 'source ~/.bash_profile' >> ~/.zshrc
```